# Error with MariaDB after brew upgrade, ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew

I am on a `mac` 12.5.1 and I have recently upgraded `brew` and suddenly I cannot log in to `mariadb`, I get:

```
$: mariadb -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have no idea why, but I cannot dump the databases and reinstall.

On phpmyadmin I get:

```bash
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
My mariadb version is 
`mariadb: stable 11.0.2 (bottled)`

If I try mariadb-upgrade:
```

$: mariadb-upgrade

```bash
Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I then completely remove mariadb and installed again but still unable to start it.

```bash
⚡➜ brew services start mariadb
==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
 ⚡➜ mysql_secure_installation
/usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use 'mariadb-secure-installation' instead

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user. If you've just installed MariaDB, and
haven't set the root password yet, you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
```